# Using triggers to export data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm pretty new with SQL and trying to figure out the way I should approach the following problem.  I have a table with the details of delivery records.  Every time a delivery is entered into this table, I want to select all rows for that particular DeliveryID and export the data returned.  Here's my table.

DeliveryRecords

```
RecordID DeliveryID ItemID Quantity RecordType          Created
    1         1       A       3        SOLD     2015-04-20 19:43:53.250
    2         1       B       4        SOLD     2015-04-20 19:43:53.261
    3         1       C       5        SOLD     2015-04-20 19:43:53.270
    4         1       C       2       RETURN    2015-04-20 19:43:53.290
    5         2       A       3        SOLD     2015-04-21 04:00:00.500
    6         2       B       2        SOLD     2015-04-21 04:00:00.510
    7         3       B       2        SOLD     2015-04-22 06:00:00.100
    8         3       C       3        SOLD     2015-04-22 06:00:00.120
    9         4       A       1       RETURN    2015-04-23 10:00:00.200
```

Is this something I can create a trigger for? and if yes, how do I get my trigger to initiate after the last row of one particular delivery is finished?

Comment: Trigger and export do not go along nicely. What kind of export do you have in mind? We have created triggers, setting some status or adding completed delivery ID into queue and then we have scheduled SQL Agent job, fetching completed deliveries and printing these for example (and marking them printed of course :))

Comment: Triggers are fired when certain events happen - you cannot control when and how many times triggers fire. Therefore, a trigger should be **very nimble** and do the least work possible. You should definitely **NOT** include time- and/or processor-intensive, long-running tasks in a trigger - don't use cursors, don't talk to external systems, don't export data into the file system - those are horribly bad choices for a trigger!

Comment: Thanks for the helpful advice... @Arvo, SQL Agent might be the solution.  I'm trying to get these exports in an xml